# Looking for cleaner way to make association list out of list of numbers

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm looking to write a procedure that will take a list in the form '(0 7 10 14) and transform it into a list '((0 . 7) (7 . 10) (10 . 14)). The procedure below will do exactly that. I think it's rather messy and can't find a simpler way to write it. Maybe I can use a built-in racket function to do this?

```
(define (simplify-path path)
    (if (null? (cddr path))
        (cons (cons (car path) (cadr path)) '())
        (begin (cons (cons (car path) (cadr path))
                     (simplify-path (cdr path))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Racket, we can do this:

```
(define (simplify-path path)
  (map cons
       (drop-right path 1)
       (rest path)))
```

It works as expected:

```
(simplify-path '(0 7 10 14))
=> '((0 . 7) (7 . 10) (10 . 14))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (simplify-path path)
  (for/list ([x path] [y (cdr path)]) (cons x y)))
```

Does it too.

- In contrast to `map`, `for/list` can take two different length lists - cuts down to length of shortest.

Answer (score 1):

written in mit-scheme.

```
(define list->assocs
  (lambda (l)
    (define pair-first-second
      (lambda (l)
        (cons (car l) (cadr l))))
    (define iter
      (lambda (l k)
        (if (eq? '() (cddr l))
            (k (pair-first-second l))
            (iter (cdr l)
                  (lambda (r)
                    (k (cons (pair-first-second l) r)))))))
    (if (or (eq? '() l)
            (eq? '() (cdr l)))
        l
        (iter l
              (lambda (x) x)))))


(list->assocs '(0 7 10 14))
```

Comment: will `iter` really be iterative though? the continuations refer to `l`, where would that reference live? `iter`'s call frame can't be reused or all `l`s would be the same. is `iter` really *not* TC-optimizable here? but this situation is commonplace when coding CPS as you did here. does that mean the CPS code is (almost) never TCO'd? I suddenly have grave doubts about all this...

Comment: @WillNess iter is iterative.  It has the complexity `O(length l)` and it crosses over `l` 2 times, once forward and once backward.  The continuation refers to `l` in the moment when we will turn back , during the second pass, from the end of the list to its head.  The code is tail called in both passes, when it goes forward it grows the heap and when it comes backward via `k` it is also tail recursive.

Comment: iter goes over the list only once, forward towards its end. when it reaches the end, it has built the chain of lambdas O(n) long. those lambdas are all tail calling each the previous one. they are building the result from its end going back over the input list. that much is clear. but they refer each to *its own* `l` (along the input list). question: where do all those `l`s point / refer to? it can't be directly to `iter`'s frame of the corresponding invocation, those frames are gone, reused, since iter is TR. I guess when the closure is created, the frame is copied. that's the answer. :)

Comment: @WillNess where do all those `l`s point / refer to? They refer to the local `lambda (l k)` and they are actually the same pointers as the `CDR`'s of the initial `l` from `lambda (l)`  But each frame of the closure of `k` looks like ``( (( l .  some-pointer to l) (k. pointer to enclosing continuation))  ((l . initial-list) (iter . pointer to func) (pair-first-second . pointer to func)) ... )``   etc.

Comment: by "local lambda" you mean the one in `(define iter (lambda (l k) ...`? that is the one I call "iter's invocation frame". I guess it must be copied when the closure is created. can't refer to the frame itself, as it is gone, as part of TCO. that's what I was grappling with.

Comment: @WillNess  The deep of the environment of each embedded lambda is as deep as it's syntactical position. local lambda = all nested lambdas, including the continuations `k`.  No frame is copied, all frames of embedded lambdas contain a pointer to the enclosing environments.  The frames of the closures created when we arrive at `null? l` point to an enclosing frame and in total a chain of frames of length of about `length(l)`.  But each frame has constant size for each `k`.

Comment: here I have to disagree with you. there is no nesting of environments precisely because `iter` is TR. the invoked `iter` has no reference to any variable in the `iter` that invoked it. each lambda's environment in the chain of lambdas has the same depth (2). it's in the code: top-level contains `list->assocs` contains {`iter` and `pair-first-second`}.

Comment: The invoked `iter` can see the `pair-first-second` in a nested environment; the innermost environment contains only `l` and `k`.  But actually we are talking about an implementation-defined feature, but in all implementations the pointed environment of each closure has constant size.

Comment: probably your confusion comes from the fact that each closure has an environment pointing to the enclosing closure which has an environment pointing to the enclosing closure, etc, and the chain grows up to the end of the list.  But in each environment there is a pointer pointing to a closure which points to the next environment frame, etc.  All the frames contain pointers and are equal in size

Comment: each `iter` is 1-deep inside `list->assocs`. this is self-evident in the code. the depth of environments does not grow, TCO in Scheme is guaranteed. the lambdas in the chain are each paired up with its environment frame each with the same depth: `cont-lambda`--`iter`--`list->assocs`.

Comment: @WillNess  yes, exactly.

Comment: @WillNess yes, and there are many kinds of frame-pointers, one pointer to the outside frame from the same level and another pointer to the first frame of the outside level.  See the implementation of K Dybvig.